# Selenium web driver find element by id on non-focus able element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How do i get the  **element id using selenium, when that element is non-focus able**.

The focus is set on that element after page is loaded?

Comment: it has to. when i load the page, the focus is on particular element which is not a text field or text area, its a container element. So how do i assert if the page when loaded the focus is on that element?

Comment: A small correction non-focus able here means the one which is not of type input text field or text area. The element is container type. So when my page is loaded, it automatically sets the focus on that. It's located at the bottom of the page, so it loads the page with that element getting focused. So i want a way so that when the page is loaded, i can assert the element id which is focused on page loaded.